# What if coordinate descent updates multiple variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The coordinate descent method update variable one at a time.
For instance, if the variable $x_i$ is selected to be updated based on Gauss-Southwell rule, then
$x_i^{(k)}=\text{argmin}_{x_i}\ f(x_1^{(k-1)},\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n^{(k-1)})$.

Is there an algorithm that updates multiple variables in each iteration?
For instance, if $x_i$ and $x_j$ are chosen to be updated, then
$x_i^{(k)},x_j^{(k)}=\text{argmin}_{x_i,x_j}\ f(x_1^{(k-1)},\dots,x_i,x_j,\dots,x_n^{(k-1)})$.

*$k$ denotes the iteration

Comment: There is “block coordinate descent”, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is called Block Coordinate Descent.

You may read about it at:

- [Analysis of the Block Coordinate Descent Method for Linear Ill Posed Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04794).
- [Convergence of Block Coordinate Descent with Diminishing Radius for Non Convex Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.03503).
- [Stanford - CME307/MS&E311: Optimization - Block Coordinate and Stochastic Gradient Decent Methods](https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande311/lecture16.pdf).

Basically it is like Jacobi iteration vs. Gauss Seidel iteration.